# Switch to full view in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have literally spent more than an hour to fix my view in Outlook 2016. I have tried every single button, tried dozens of Google searches, but all I have managed to do is get images of what I want to achieve but not how to do it, it is driving me insane...

Out of nowhere my Outlook inbox suddenly looks like this:

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3MvL.png)

Obviously I dont want this mess of a layout and I am trying to go back to this sane layout:

[Target Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nknWX.png)

I am at the end of my wits and really frustrated. What setting is it? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target layout you want to achieve is Compact view.

In Outlook: Click View > Change View > Compact. Then you are able to go back to your previous layout.

[Change to Compact View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRANS.png)

Hope this can be helpful.